# Showing the limit of a flow must be an equilibrium point under certain restrictions.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm stumped on how to approach this one:

Consider the autonomous ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
(at least) continuously differentiable. Let $\phi(t; x_0)$ be a solution such that
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow\infty}\phi(t; x_0) = a$$
for a certain $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $a$ must be a critical point (equilibrium) of the system.

Now intuitively I get that since $\phi(t,x_0) \rightarrow a$ we in a sense have that $\dot{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$ since the speed at which our solution approaches $a$ becomes slower and slower. But how to rigorously put this, and how $f$ being continuously differentiable has got me stuck.

Can anyone help me along the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
f(x)=f(a)+O(|x-a|)
$$
Given $\varepsilon_0>0$, we have
$$
|\phi(t,x_0)-a|<\varepsilon_0 \;\;\mbox{ if } t>t_0
$$
and
$$
|\phi'(t)-f(a)|=|f(\phi(t,x_0))-f(a)|\le M|\phi(t,x_0)-a|<M\varepsilon_0\; \mbox{ if } t>t_0
$$

Now if we take $t_1$ and $t_2>t_0$, using the previous inequalities, we obtain
$$
2\varepsilon_0>|\phi(t_2,x_0)-\phi(t_1,x_0)|=\left|\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\phi'(t)\,dt\right|\ge\left|\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(a)\,dt\right|-\left|\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\phi'(t)-f(a)\,dt\right|\\ >|f(a)(t_2-t_1)|-M\varepsilon_0|t_2-t_1|
$$
Then
$$
|f(a)|<\frac{2\varepsilon_0+M\varepsilon_0|t_2-t_1|}{|t_2-t_1|}
$$
Since we can take $\varepsilon_0$ so small as we want, we conclude that $f(a)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm curious, it looks like you used that $f$ is Lipschitz in finding $M$. I thought that Lipschitz was stronger that continuous differentiability?

Comment: In other words, continuously differentiable only requires a derivative that exists and is continuous, but not necessarily bounded. So such an $M$ doesn't have to exist.

Comment: $M$ is not a global bound.  Continuous differentiability implies Lipschitz in any compact set. In particular, in $\{|u-a|\le\varepsilon_0\}$.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Neato!